# netbeans показ в редакторе длинных строк

Tags: php, netbeans, редактор

Некоторое время назад мне знакомый прислал настройки для редактора netbeans для языка php. Я их импортировал себе и сразу после импорта обратил внимание, что в редакторе длинные строки показываются в несколько строк. Именно показываются (номер строки один), а не переносятся (разбиваются) на несколько строк. Тогда мне это показалось неудобно и я это как-то отключил. Как я это сделал сейчас к сожалению не помню...

А вот сейчас появилась потребность именно в этой функции, но нигде не могу найти как ее включить обратно.

Comment: Сервис, Параметры, Редактор, Форматирование, Перенос строк?

Comment: А это разве не разбиение на строки? Там было, что строка оставалась какой же длинной (без переносов), просто показывалась как несколько строк.